# React.js checkbox example in v0.13.3?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

Brand new to React (looked up on wikipedia two days ago) so downloaded current version v0.13.3 from home page. Trying to find a checkbox example (check a box, something happens - like a label appears or something). This one works in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d10xyqu1/1/). Discovering with much frustration that that things are often deprecated on new releases of React, so older examples don't work anymore. On this one, the browser says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of undefined`)
```

which is not even in the code. Looked at bunches of articles, tried bunches of things like

```
React.renderComponent → React.render
```

Anyone know the magic tricks required to make this example work with the current version of v0.13.3?

Or anyone know of a working checkbox example in v0.13.3?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle with the code you have tried for v0.13.3?

Comment: Sure. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/airwwwave/jgkcxusb/). Commented lines are things I've tried. [article1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581688/react-facebook-managed-state-of-controlled-checkboxes), [article2](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), [article3](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html), [article4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615779/react-checkbox-not-sending-onchange), [article5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320363/cannot-read-property-reactautobindmap-of-undefined), [article6](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2661)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the rendering of the element.

```
React.renderComponent(
    CrossoutCheckbox({text: "Text Text", complete: false}),document.body
);
```

The right syntax, if you don't want to use JSX is the following:

```
React.render(
    React.createElement(
        CrossoutCheckbox, {text: "Test text", complete: false}),
        document.body);
```

The direct creation of an element was removed in the 0.13.0, as you can read in the change log https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

> Deprecated patterns that warned in 0.12 no longer work: most prominently, calling component classes without using JSX or React.createElement and using non-component functions with JSX or createElement

Comment: Thanks! I tried that one (as you can see from the last commented out area in the fiddle where I was trying things), but I had two syntax errors! I needed to replace the opening parens after CrossoutCheckbox with a comma and space. And also needed to delete the closing parens and semicolon. Which your code did. Thank you!

Comment: Well!!Try to use JSX instead of the createElement syntax. The code will be more clear. All the modern IDE support it and you can add some gulp/grunt automation to prebuild your code.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I had thought the [initial working example](http://jsfiddle.net/d10xyqu1/1/) was using JSX. It is right? But I guess I didn't realize some of the solutions I was reading about and trying were NOT using JSX. That's a lightbulb going off there! Yes, ultimately I would like a JSX solution. So, I'll keep trying. Thanks again.